# Can I view the progress of a LUKS encryption that was initiated in the GUI? Alternately can I calculate it?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, encryption, luks

I am encrypting a 2TB internal hard drive with LUKS using the default Disks app (see image). I am aware that these things are supposed to take time (I've seen days, even weeks, in my cursory googling), but I would like to be able to track its progress.

1. Is there a way to do so after the fact, perhaps on the command line?
2. (For future reference) Is there a way to do it before hand, even if encrypting using the GUI?
3. Can I estimate how long this should take, since I know what kind of SATA cable I'm using, what my RAM is, what my external HDD is, etc...?

[image: Screenshot of GUI showing the job is still running]

Comment: As I said, I'm using SATA @David

Comment: I suppose the word "external" made you assume "USB" which would be fair, but I thought using the term "SATA cable" would imply SATA to SATA. I am treating this drive as an external drive, but I am hooking it up like an internal drive. Apologies for any confusion. In any event, the most important thing is that it is not my main drive. @David

Comment: It would be a good idea to change external to internal in your question. Even if you plan on removing one drive later for now it is simply 2 drives INSIDE the same box.

Comment: @David Done, thank you for the suggestion